# Connect to Redshift using Python using IAM Role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'am using sqlalchemy and psycopg2 to connect python to redshift.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@hostname:port/database_name')
```

I want to avoid using my password to connect to redshift and using IAM Role.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AWS offers a way to request temporary credentials for access to Redshift clusters. Boto3 implements `get_cluster_credentials`, allowing you to do something like the following. Ensure that you have followed the [instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html) on setting up your IAM Users and Roles.

```
def db_connection():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    RS_PORT = 5439
    RS_USER = 'myDbUser'
    DATABASE = 'myDb'
    CLUSTER_ID = 'myCluster'
    RS_HOST = 'myClusterHostName'

    client = boto3.client('redshift')

    cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=RS_USER,
                                               DbName=DATABASE,
                                          ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_ID,
                                               AutoCreate=False)

    try:
      conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=RS_HOST,
        port=RS_PORT,
        user=cluster_creds['DbUser'],
        password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'],
        database=DATABASE
      )
      return conn
    except psycopg2.Error:
      logger.exception('Failed to open database connection.')
```

Answer (score 4):

AWS provides no convenient wrapper for IAM creds in python like they do for their JDBC driver. You need to make a call to the GetClusterCredentials endpoint manually and then pass in the returned username and password to `create_engine`. Looks something like:

```
def get_redshift_credentials():
    role_creds = get_role_credentials()
    client = boto3.client(
        'redshift',
        region_name=CLUSTER_REGION,
        aws_access_key_id=role_creds['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=role_creds['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=role_creds['SessionToken'],
    )
    response = client.get_cluster_credentials(
        DbUser=PGUSER,
        ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER,
    )
    return response

creds = get_redshift_credentials()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://{creds.DbUser}:{creds.DbPassword}@hostname:port/database_name'.format(creds))
```

Comment: The credential user are like ; IAM:username,  and then create_engine seems to always regard that IAM is the username,  is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Since some time ago AWS has a native [Redshift connector](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver) for Python.

It supports connecting using IAM, given your IAM credentials allows you to call [get-cluster-credentials](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift/get-cluster-credentials.html).

Example:

```py
import redshift_connector

conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    iam=True,
    database='dev',
    db_user='<username>', # the database user in call to get-cluster-credentials
    cluster_identifier='my-redshift-cluster', # identifier of your cluster
    profile='redshift_profile' # profile in ~./aws/config with correct permissions
 )

cursor = redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT 1;')
```

A nice feature of this connector is that it calls `describe-clusters` internally using the `cluster_identifier`, so you don't even need to specify host and port.

Comment: any ideas how you'd do this if your redshift cluster was in a different account to the one you're profile is in?

Comment: Unfortunately not, have not worked with Redshift for some time and have no access to any accounts or clusters to try it out. But I would assume it works out of the box as long you have the correct permissions (including describe-clusters) on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

AWS IAM users are different from Redshift database users. Although Redshift is a (very distant) relative of postgres, it doesn't allow passwordless connections yet, afaik.

EDIT:

My answer is no longer applicable, check other answers for relevant code snippets.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can  (as of January 2018) call `get_cluster_credentials` to get temporary credentials to access a Redshift cluster.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.get_cluster_credentials

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit to indicate my answer no longer applying. When I was answering back then, I didn't find this function. Either I'm bad at searching or it was added to boto some time later.