# Unable to connect to Redshift from lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, timeout, amazon-redshift, serverless

I have created a serverless Redshift cluster and want to use lambda to read/write the data from Redshift.

- Configured the VPC, subnet and security group in lambda
- same VPC, subnet and security group is present for serverless Redshift.

My lambda is timing out without establishing Redshift connection.

I referred [Unable to connect to aws redshift from python within lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319128/unable-to-connect-to-aws-redshift-from-python-within-lambda) and ensured below :

- Redshift Serverless VPC, subnet and security group is similar to lambda VPC, subnet and security group
- lambda role has AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

but still, I unable to establish redshift connection from lambda. It's not throwing any error but timing out.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group on the Redshift cluster and the Security Group on the AWS Lambda function? Please note that using the same Security Group for both does _not_ guarantee they can communicate with each other since Security Groups are applied individually to each resource. It is generally better to use separate Security Groups for the Lambda function and Database since each require different permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using the "same VPC, subnet and security group is present for serverless Redshift".

Please note that using the same Security Group for both does *not* guarantee they can communicate with each other since Security Groups are applied individually to each resource. It is generally better to use separate Security Groups for the Lambda function and Database since each require different permissions.

I would recommend:

- A Security Group for the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) that permits all Outbound access, *and*
- A Security Group for the Database (`DB-SG`) that permits all Inbound access from `Lambda-SG` on port 5439 (Redshift)

That is, `DB-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG` in the Inbound rules, which means that the Lambda function would be granted connectivity to the Database.

Comment: alright ! Is it okay to use default VPC and default subnets for Redshift and lambda or should I create new VPC ?

Comment: You can use the Default VPC. The Lambda function should be connected to a **private subnet**. Typically databases go in a private subnet too, for extra security.

Comment: I am still stuck ! created a VPC, private subnets (no routing to IGW). created lambda-sg and allowed all outbound access, created redshift-sg and allowed lambda-sg to 5439 and all to all traffic.
can it be related to IAM role or host? I am using 
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
        host='default-workgroup.339712756193.ap-south-1.redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com',
        database='dev',
        port=5439,
        user='admin',
        password='admin'
        )

Comment: When I try to resolve that DNS name, it converts to `vpce-05ff39092ffa8a1ba-9lyevnb8.vpce-svc-0cea2c88600119d4f.ap-south-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`. The `vpce` bit makes me think it is using a VPC Endpoint to connect with Redshift. If so, check the Security Group on the VPC Endpoint and make sure it is accepting inbound traffic from the Security Group associated with the Lambda function.